# Adding to the Rear of a doubly linked Circular Buffer of Integer (java)

Tags: java, circular-buffer

I'm trying to add to the rear of the buffer but when I add to the rear it seems to be trailing behind by a number. Is there any fix for this?

This was the error I got when I ran it through my professors tester.

---

Error: add part 2
Expected: "R [2, 1] F"
Received: "R [1] F"
Error: add part 3
Expected: "R [3, 2, 1] F"
Received: "R [2, 1] F"

---

```
public void addRear(Integer e) throws BufferFullException {
        if (isFull()) throw new BufferFullException("Buffer full");
        DNode insert = new DNode(e);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            this.front =  insert;
            this.rear = insert;
            this.front.next = this.rear;
            this.rear.prev = this.front;
            size++;
        } else if (size == 0) {
            this.rear = insert;
            this.rear.prev = this.front;
            this.front.next = this.rear;
            size++;
        } else {
            this.rear.next = insert;
            insert.prev = this.rear;
            this.rear = insert;
            size++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between the conditions `isEmpty()` and `size == 0` ?

Comment: I have a separate method it calls to                                                                        
` public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size==0;
    }`

Comment: Well, then the block after `else if (size == 0)` can never execute.

Comment: when I put the size==1, it still reads off the same error

Comment: I recommend starting over and first writing in pseudocode what you want to do to implement a circular buffer.